# Prevent eclipse to perform save actions if code does not compile

Tags: java, eclipse

Is there a way to configure Eclipse to prevent save actions on a file unless it is free of compile errors, or the entire project is error-free?
Sometimes you need to save a file because you reached the end of the work day or similar, but are not done with your edits. This can be especially annoying if the file is ill-formed wrt. braces or has issues inside lambdas because it may cause formatting or import organization to throw away larger parts of your imports or even break code after your edits.

Comment: Not something I know how to do, unfortunately. There are even some bugs related to this, like https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=547052.

Comment: You can turn off the save actions in "Java > Editor > Save Actions" in the Preferences.

Comment: @PetrJaneček Eclipse platform and JDT have moved to GitHub. [Make sure it has reported here, best with a pull request](https://github.com/eclipse-jdt/eclipse.jdt.ui/issues).

Comment: Turning off save actions is the only way I see to react to this, but it is not really a workaround as there can be actions in the save actions list that cannot be applied by hotkey, right? I mean the formatting itself isn't an issue. The entire code cleanup is.